# Can't find the issues and latches are generated

Tags: vhdl

My code generates two latches, could please someone help me finding why?
According to Xilinx ISE latches are generated because of "try_counter" which is a counter for how many times you get a numeric sequence wrong. (which is the main point of my code).

I don't know what else to do.

```
entity moore is
Port ( badgeSx : in  STD_LOGIC;
            badgeDx : in  STD_LOGIC;
            col : in std_logic_vector (1 to 3);
            row : in std_logic_vector (1 to 4);
            clk : in std_logic;
            rst : in std_logic;
            unlock : out  STD_LOGIC
        );
end moore;

architecture Behavioral of moore is
type stato is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9);
    signal current_state,next_state : stato;
    signal badge : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal count, new_count: integer range 0 to 28;
    signal temp_unlock : std_logic :='0';
    signal timeover : std_logic :='0';
begin
    badge <= badgeDx & badgeSx; --concatenazione dei badge
--processo sequenziale
    current_state_register: process(clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if (rst = '1') then 
            current_state <= s0; 
            count <= 0;
        else 
            current_state <= next_state; 
            count <= new_count;
    end if;
end if;
end process;


process (current_state,badge,col,row,timeover)
    variable try_counter: integer range 0 to 3;
    begin
    case current_state is

    when s0 =>
        try_counter := 0;
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <='0';
        if(badge ="01" and row = "0000" and col = "000" ) then
            next_state <= s1;
        else 
            next_state <= s0;
        end if;

    when s1 =>
        temp_unlock <= '1';
        unlock <= '0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s2;
        elsif (timeover ='1' or badge = "10" or try_counter = 3) then
            next_state <= s0;
        else 
            next_state <= s1;
            try_counter := try_counter +1;
        end if; 

    when s2 => 
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <='0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s2;
        else
            next_state <= s3;
        end if;

    when s3 =>
        temp_unlock <= '1';
        unlock <= '0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s4;
        elsif (timeover ='1' or badge = "10" or try_counter = 3) then
            next_state <= s0;
        else 
            next_state <= s1;
            try_counter := try_counter +1;
        end if;

    when s4 =>
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <='0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s4;
        else
            next_state <= s5;
        end if;

    when s5 =>
        temp_unlock <= '1';
        unlock <= '0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s6;
        elsif (timeover ='1' or badge = "10" or try_counter = 3) then
            next_state <= s0;
        else 
            next_state <= s1;
            try_counter := try_counter +1;
        end if;

    when s6 =>
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <='0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s6;
        else
            next_state <= s7;
        end if;

    when s7 =>
        temp_unlock <= '1';
        unlock <= '0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s8;
        elsif (timeover ='1' or badge = "10" or try_counter = 3) then
            next_state <= s0;
        else 
            next_state <= s1;
            try_counter := try_counter +1;
        end if;

    when s8 =>
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <='0';
        if (badge = "00" and col ="001" and row = "0001" and timeover = '0') then
            next_state <= s8;
        else
            next_state <= s9;
        end if;

    when s9 =>
        temp_unlock <= '0';
        unlock <= '1';
        if (badge = "10") then
            next_state <= s0;
        else
            next_state <= s5;
        end if;
    when others =>
     next_state <= s0;
    end case;
  end process;

Contatore_TIMER : process(temp_unlock,count)
 begin
   if temp_unlock = '1' then 
          if count = 28 then 
             new_count<=0;
             timeover<='1';
          else
             new_count<=count+1;
             timeover<='0';
          end if;
   else 
       new_count<=0;
       timeover <= '0';
   end if;
   end process;
 end Behavioral;
```

The code nearly works as expected (I mean it compiles and I don't get any error) but the RTL schematic isn't what it is supposed to be since it synthesises latches in the process.

[image: Latches]

Answer (score 2):

In the apparently combinatorial process with `process (current_state,badge,col,row,timeover)`, the variable `try_counter` is used to store information (sequential behaviour), which is only updated when process evaluation is triggered.  This will very likely to generate the 2 latches, which matches the value range from 0 to 3 for `try_counter`.

To fix this, you can define `try_counter` as a signal, and include it in the sensitivity list for the process.

Having `try_counter` as a signal will also ease debugging, since the current state can easily be inspected in waveforms.

Comment: I switched try_counter from a variable to a signal ( signal try_counter : integer range 0 to 3) ; and I have also changed try_counter := try_counter +1; into try_counter <= try_counter +1; since now it's a signal but latches are still generated

Comment: To avoid latches you must assign a value to the try_counter signal in every branch of your conditional statements.  Otherwise, the last state of the value needs to be stored for the branches without an explicit assignment, which requires a latch.

Comment: and how can I do that in my code? I mean I need try_counter to be assigned only in the first state because then I need to increase it as much as possible (max 3) and I need to save its value until try_counter reaches 3. Is possible then to avoid latches in this situation?

Comment: You must look at the condition for updating `try_counter`, since in the code above it is updated based on events of the signals in the sensitivity list, which is probably not what you actually want.  The assign, and thus update, of `try_counter` should probably go into the `current_state_register` process or similar clocked process, so it is updated at a clock edge, like regular synchronous state.  But again, that depends on the actual functionality that you want to implement.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Try_counter needs to be updated every time someone gets the wrong code, the main point of my code is to recognise a badge and a correct numeric sequence (which I set to be 1-1-1-1) and then unlock a door if I make 3 wrong attempts the machine returns in its first state and I need to scan a badge again, while if I make less than 3 wrong attempts it goes in its second state in which I don't have to scan a badge again

Comment: The I suggest you update `try_counter` in a sequential process (`rising_edge(clk)`), when the condition for wrong code is true.